# How to avoid fixing extracted methods code snippet at top or bottom of Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-arctic-fox

After updating Android Studio to **Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1** version, The IDE fixes extracted methods code snippet at top or bottom of screen depending on scrolling direction. As you can see in the image below, it's annoying because it fills a large part of screen.

[image]

Is there any way to avoid showing extracted methods code snippet?

Comment: Thank you for posting this question.  It is worse in my case.  It can be at the top, bottom, or middle.  If can block some other functions such as search. I have to restart AS to fix this. I hope Google will fix this ASAP because method extraction is used frequently.  It is a major nuisance.

Comment: I hope we find a solution to it soon.

Comment: t is displayed on random locations. Especially after switching tab.

Whenever i extract method, I have to restart IDE :/

Comment: There is a bug report for this issue in the Android Studio issue tracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/213134273 It seems like they closed it due to not enough information to reproduce. So i added a "how to reproduce" description, a screen recording and a link to this question. Hope they reopen the issue report and fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an answer here. it fixes the bug at the expense of having popup windows appear whenever you want to refactor something. i should have stayed on 4.2 XD

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68748331/10637400

credit goes @Chris Clarke.

maybe this helps reduce your time googling