# Android Studio strange code sub-windows after upgrade to Arctic Fox (2020.3.1)

Tags: android-studio

After Android Studio upgraded itself to version Arctic Fox, I now get these strange sub-windows in my code editor that I can't get rid of. If I click in either of the 2 sub-windows (a one-line window at the top or a 5-line window underneath it (see pic below), it scrolls to the code in question and the sub-windows disappear. But as soon as I navigate away from that code, these sub-windows mysteriously reappear. I can't figure out how to get rid of this.

I restarted Studio and it seemed to go away. Then I refactored a piece of code (Extract to Method Ctrl+Alt+M) and then these windows appeared again. Sometimes these windows appear on a 2nd monitor instead of on top of the code area on the monitor with Android Studio. But eventually they end up back on top of my code editor window.

I have searched hi and low for what this is. Studio help, new features, blog, etc. I am sure that I am just using the wrong terminology to find the answer, so hoping someone else knows.

[image]

Comment: Now, I have found that if I enter Full Screen Mode and then Exit Full Screen Mode, that window goes away. Until I Extract to Method again, anywhere, and it is back.

Comment: Found similar post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66238377/android-studio-is-showing-a-popup-window-in-the-code-editor-how-can-i-get-rid-o

Comment: I have the same problem. The popup goes away and doesn't come back after restarting android studio (until I do extract-to-method again). I didn't change any settings. If it should really be there, it should also be there after a restart. But it isn't. I presume it's a bug that the popup is there in the first place.

Comment: There is a bug report for this issue in the Android Studio issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/213134273 It seems like they closed it due to not enough information to reproduce. So i added a "how to reproduce" description, a screen recording and a link to this question. Hope they reopen the issue report and fix it.

Comment: A "feature" no one asked for, no one wants, and no easy way to get rid of it.  I get the horrid thing just navigating backwards and forwards through code using the "Forward" and "Backward" hot keys.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just stumbled upon the same thing (strange windows upon attempting to refactor some code after updating to Arctic Fox). After a lot of searching around the options/menus/internet this fixed it for me:

Navigate to:

*File > Settings... > Editor > Code Editing*

under

*Refactorings > Specify refactoring options:*

select

*In modal dialogs*

Press OK.

Fingers crossed refactoring works.

Further step: *Restart Android Studio*

Comment: I did this Chris, In my editor that was showing one of these subwindows, showing code from a previous refactor. After clicking OK, the subwindow did not go away. Refactoring does now show the modal dialog. But I still get the subwindows that will not go away. Perhaps I am missing something from your explanation.

Comment: I restarted Android Studio after making the change above. I tested Refactor Method and all seems to be working now. Thanks much Chris!

Comment: I should also say, that I wouldn't mind trying out the new 'inline' instead of 'modal dialog' feature, IF... I could figure out how to make that work and then go away. But there seems to be no tips/hints on how to work with that window when it appears. Would love to hear from someone that may have perhaps figured it out.

Comment: @JJJones_3860 glad you got it working! perhaps amongst all the things I did try, I missed a step. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: seems like android tooling has become just as bad as ios with android studio looking more and more like the cluster f* of bugs that is Xcode