# Android studio Arctic Fox small preview window doesn't go away

Tags: android-studio-3.2

After new update to `Android studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1`. A small preview popup window appears and blocks certain portion of screen, it doesn't go away sometimes I have to quit android studio for to make it disappear. I am not sure if it's a bug or a feature. Does anyone have similar issue? Couldn't find similar post on stackoverflow this seems to be specific to this version of Android Studio. Image attached.[image: stud]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For mac, goto `Preferences`

```
Preferences -> Editor -> Code editing
```

Select "`in modal dialog`" under `refactorings section.`

For windows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68748331/3952885